# Array of Objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class

So I have this custom Class (which i later build a inheritence tree from) but thie root class is perfect for creating a array of the stat modifiers for character classes in my game instead  of having to create a 2d array so i can store 8 doubles PER class but JAva doesn't like my code what am i doing wrong?

CharGen is my class, i can instantiant and extend it fine on its own
NumOfClasses is a int i used several times to set various array to the size for the total classes in the system, both those work fine.
The array of CharGen tosses a error

```
private CharGen CClassAttributeModifier[] = new CharGen[NumOfClasses];//expects a token { after the ;
CClassAttributeModifier[0] = new CharGen();//expects a } after ;
```

But that just seems wrong especially since the [0] set up is only a test, it's not being built right after the decleration it's going to be built in the class constructor as i build out the array for all the classes data, names, descriptions , attributes, etc which once set will be used to load all the data for selected classes later when you selected it in game

Comment: Paste the relevant non-compiling code, and the exact error message you get from the compiler. The one which explains what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two lines of code are never legal together, because the first one is a member variable declaration (which must appear at class scope) and the second is a statement (which must appear inside a method or initialization block.) How to fix this depends on what you want. If it's supposed to be a member variable, then move the second statement into the constructor for the class. If, on the other hand, this is a local variable in a method, then remove the "private", which can't be used in local variable declarations.

Comment: Ah thanks I'll try that, like i said the second line was just for testing and i was hoping i could do testing outside the method.
That did it it was just location problem!